# Better way to Code Dictionary Lookup?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Probably a very simple issue, but in writing some code where I have a mapping dictionary, I found that handling nulls and such has made my code look disgusting. Is there a better way to do this?

```
int brokerId = 0; // set a default value in case nothing is found
if(myTrade.Counterparty!=null) // dont bother if counterparty is null
  if (resolutionMap.Result["Broker"].ContainsKey((myTrade.Counterparty)))
    if (resolutionMap.Result["Broker"][myTrade.Counterparty] != null)
      primeBrokerId = Convert.ToInt32(resolutionMap.Result["Broker"][myTrade.Counterparty]);
```

Comment: It's not easy to give suggestions without knowing a lot more context, but avoiding nested dictionaries and disallowing nulls in the first place would probably help.

Comment: you can easily write an extension method on your resolutionMap (whatever that is) to expose one method wrapping those defensive logic; once you have one extension, you might find it's useful to write another one, so eventually, each extension method can be very simple and clean

Comment: Be more specific on what you mean by "better".  You can get rid of nested `if`s by using &&.  You can get rid of the multiple dictionary lookups by using `TryGetValue`.  You can encapsulate parts of your code in methods.  You can reduce redundant code by storing results in variables.

Comment: It may help to avoid having things that can be null. Using code contracts can then ensure at compile time that you haven't set said things to null. A trade would always have a counterparty, right? Also writing classes for meaning rather than using a naked dictionary may help with readability and separate concerns of access and storage and avoid the magic "Broker" string.

Answer (score 3):

Store the value of `resolutionMap.Result["Broker"]` into a variable rather than looking it up multiple times e.g. `var broker = resolutionMap.Result["Broker"];`.

Also use `TryGetValue()` instead of `ContainsKey()` e.g.

```
CounterParty counterParty;
if (broker.TryGetValue(myTrade.Counterparty, out counterParty) && counterParty != null) { ....
```